# No integer solutions for $x^5 - 3y^5 = 2008$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have a tutorial question (not homework) that asks to prove that there exist  no integer solution for 
$$x^5 - 3y^5 = 2008$$

I originally thought I would solve it by taking all cases $\bmod 10$, but realised that would be a massive workload, and also realised it fell through instantly as $x = 1 \bmod 1, y = 1 \bmod 1$, gave $x^5 - 3y^5 = 8 \bmod 10$ instantly. I only thought that method might work because we were doing mod proofs directly prior to the question.

I have absolutely no idea how to solve this problem without using computation, any tips or methods?

Comment: If $\pmod {10}$ doesn't work you could try other moduli.  Maybe the $3$ in the equation makes you think of $3^n$.  I would try $\pmod 9$  The fact that $2008 \equiv 0 \pmod 8$ seems interesting as well.  No guarantees.

Comment: Why do you think the workload would be so massive?  You don't actually need to do every _pair_ - for a given prime $p$ just compute a table of all the fifth powers, mod $p$, and then a table of three times all the fifth powers; checking to see whether the shift of any given number shows up on the other is basically an $O(1)$ operation, and so you should be able to check modulo any given prime $p$ in $O(p)$ steps pretty easily.  This isn't _great_, but it's not bad at all.

Comment: @RossMillikan Unfortunately neither of those suggestions works; every odd number is a fifth power mod $8$, and $2008$ is $1$ mod $9$.

Comment: @Mike:  Playing a bit more,  also every number is a fifth power mod $9$.  It seemed like a good shot to me.  To me, it would be the next try.  Looks like Dan Brumleve had a better thought than mine.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275797/show-15x2-7y2-9-has-no-integer-solutions  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131186/no-integer-solutions-and-congruences   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419653/proving-there-are-no-integer-solutions-for-3x2-9y3  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702398/how-to-prove-no-integer-solutions  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583126/x3y4-7-has-no-integer-solutions   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725291/show-that-x2-x-12-3y5-has-no-integer-solutions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: Try mod $11$ instead, noting that both $x^5$ and $y^5$ are in $\{-1,0,1\}$.  The intuition behind choosing $11$ is Fermat's little theorem (all tenth powers mod $11$ are either $0$ or $1$).

Answer (score 2):

**Fermat Theorem : For any a$\in$Z and prime p, it's well known that $a^p=a (mod\space\ p)$**. $\Longrightarrow$ $a^{11}=a(mod\space\ 11)$. So it follows $a^{10}=1(mod\space\ 11)$ $\Longleftrightarrow (a^{5})^{2}=1(mod \space\ 11)$. So from here $a^5=\{-1,0,1\} (mod\space\ 11)$.
So having established this and also knowing that $2008=6(mod\space\ 11)$ the rest is easy considering the possible residues of $x^5-3y^5 (mod\space\ 11)$.

$\longrightarrow$ And in conclusion the equation has no integer solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure how you get from $a^{10}\equiv1\pmod{11}$ to $a^{5}\equiv -1,0,1\pmod{11}$. Fermat's Little Thm only gives $a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$ if $a,p$ are relatively prime.

Comment: @Marconius Firstly Fermat's little theorem doesn't state that **a and b** must be relatively prime. It only says that **p** must be prime. Secondly that jump I have done from $a^{10}$ to $a^{5}$ it's just taking the square root of 1 from  $a^{10}$ which is $-1$ or $1$, also adding the exclusion  case where $a^5=0(mod\space\  11)$ intuitively.